# angular-rails-templates ng-include infinite digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using [angular-rails-templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) and trying to use `ng-include` each time I try to use it, I get an infinite digest.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   |   ├── include.html
|   ├── views
│   │   ├── layouts
│   │   |   ├── application.html.erb
```

`application.html.erb`

```
<div ng-include="'assets/templates/include.html'"></div>
```

I've tried all sorts of variations, including no single quotes, just `include.html`, `templates/include.html` but they all throw me into an infinite digest. Am I missing something simple?